# Consulta no BD com erro (CodeIgniter PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, algoritmo-de-busca

Alguem poderia auxiliar com este erro?

No BD tenho a tabela cities e estou tentando listar cidades, ja fiz diversas alteracoes e nao funciona.

Quando listar as cidades vou melhorar a consulta, tenho mais tabelas com outras informacoes que peecisam ser exibidas.

Segue abaixo arquivos do projeto.

Mensagem de erro:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: Buscar

Filename: pages/busca.php

Line Number: 31

Backtrace:

File: D:\BF\meusite\application\views\frontend\pages\busca.php
Line: 31
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\BF\meusite\application\libraries\Template.php
Line: 29
Function: view

File: D:\BF\meusite\application\controllers\Pages.php
Line: 37
Function: load

File: D:\BF\meusite\index.php
Line: 322
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: pages/busca.php

Line Number: 31

Backtrace:

File: D:\BF\meusite\application\views\frontend\pages\busca.php
Line: 31
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\BF\meusite\application\libraries\Template.php
Line: 29
Function: view

File: D:\BF\meusite\application\controllers\Pages.php
Line: 37
Function: load

File: D:\BF\meusite\index.php
Line: 322
Function: require_once
```

**Controller**

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Buscar extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('menus_model');

        $this->data['menus'] = $this->menus_model->getMenus();
        $this->data['menu_ativo'] = '';

        $this->data['header'] = $this->load->view('frontend/includes/header.php', $this->data, true);
        $this->data['navigation'] = $this->load->view('frontend/includes/navigation.php', $this->data, true);
        $this->data['footer'] = $this->load->view('frontend/includes/footer.php', $this->data, true);
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->load->model("Buscar_model");
        $lista = $this->Buscar_model-> buscaTodos();
        $dados = array('Buscar' => $lista);
        $this->load->view('frontend/pages/busca.php', $dados);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
    <?php

class Buscar_model extends CI_Model{

    public function buscaTodos(){
                $this->load->database(); //carrego a library de banco de dados

        return $this->db->get('cities')->result_array(); //retorna os nossos dados
    } 
}
```

**View**

```
 <section class="section">
        <div class="categories-body">
            <div class="container">

            <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Descrição</th>
                    </tr>
            <?php foreach ($Buscar as $busca) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $busca['city_name'] ?> </td>
                    <td><?= $busca['state_uf'] ?> </td>
                </tr>
             <?php endforeach ?>
            </table>
```

**Libaries:  File: D:\BF\meusite\application\libraries\Template.php**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Template {
    var $ci;

    function __construct()  {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    function load($tipo_view, $pagina = null, $data = null, $template = 'default.php') {

        if ( ! is_null( $pagina ) ) {
            if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/frontend/'.$tipo_view.'/'.$pagina ) ) {
                $body_view_path = 'frontend/'.$tipo_view.'/'.$pagina;
            }
            else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/frontend/'.$tipo_view.'/'.$pagina.'.php' ) )  {
                $body_view_path = 'frontend/'.$tipo_view.'/'.$pagina.'.php';
            }
            else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/frontend/'.$pagina ) ) {
                $body_view_path = 'frontend/'.$pagina;
            }
            else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/frontend/'.$pagina.'.php' ) ) {
                $body_view_path = 'frontend/'.$pagina.'.php';
            }
            else {
                show_error('Unable to load the requested file: frontend/' . $tipo_view.'/'.$pagina.'.php');
            }

            $body = $this->ci->load->view($body_view_path, $data, TRUE);

            if ( is_null($data) ) {
                $data = array('body' => $body);
            }
            else if ( is_array($data) ) {
                $data['body'] = $body;
            }
            else if ( is_object($data) ) {
                $data->body = $body;
            }
        }

        $this->ci->load->view('frontend/templates/'.$template, $data);
    }

    function load_admin($tipo_view, $pagina = null, $data = null, $template = 'default.php') {

        if ( ! is_null( $pagina ) ) {
            if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/admin/'.$tipo_view.'/'.$pagina ) ) {
                $body_view_path = 'admin/'.$tipo_view.'/'.$pagina;
            }
            else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/admin/'.$tipo_view.'/'.$pagina.'.php' ) )  {
                $body_view_path = 'admin/'.$tipo_view.'/'.$pagina.'.php';
            }
            else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/admin/'.$pagina ) ) {
                $body_view_path = 'admin/'.$pagina;
            }
            else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/admin/'.$pagina.'.php' ) ) {
                $body_view_path = 'admin/'.$pagina.'.php';
            }
            else {
                show_error('Unable to load the requested file: admin/' . $tipo_view.'/'.$pagina.'.php');
            }

            $body = $this->ci->load->view($body_view_path, $data, TRUE);

            if ( is_null($data) ) {
                $data = array('body' => $body);
            }
            else if ( is_array($data) ) {
                $data['body'] = $body;
            }
            else if ( is_object($data) ) {
                $data->body = $body;
            }
        }

        $this->ci->load->view('admin/templates/'.$template, $data);
    }

    function load_admin_login($data = array()) {
        $this->ci->load->view('admin\templates\login.php', $data);
    }

    function load_from_db($tipo_view, $pagina = null, $data = null, $template = 'default.php') {

        if ( ! is_null( $pagina ) ) {

            $CI =& get_instance();

            $CI->db->select('corpo, titulo');
            $query = $CI->db->get_where('paginas', array('url' => $pagina))->result_array();
            if (empty($query)) {
                show_error('Unable to load the requested file: '.$pagina);
            } else {
                $body = $query[0]['corpo'];
                $titulo = $query[0]['titulo'];
            }

            if ( is_null($data) ) {
                $data = array('body' => $body);
            }
            else if ( is_array($data) ) {
                $data['body'] = $body;
                $data['title'] .= $titulo;
            }
            else if ( is_object($data) ) {
                $data->body = $body;
            }
        }

        $this->ci->load->view('frontend/templates/'.$template, $data);
    }

}
```

**Controller: D:\BF\meusite\application\controllers\Pages.php**

```
<?php
```

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

```
public function view($page = 'home') {

    $this->load->model('menus_model');


    $data = array();

    $data['base_url'] = base_url();

    $data['title'] = $page;

    if ($page == "home") {
        $data['title'] = 'Home';
    }

    $data['menus'] = $this->menus_model->getMenus();
    $data['menu_ativo'] = $page;

    $this->load->model('paginas_model');


    $data['events'] = array();

    $data['header'] = $this->load->view('frontend/includes/header.php', $data, true);
    $data['navigation'] = $this->load->view('frontend/includes/navigation.php', $data, true);
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('frontend/includes/footer.php', $data, true);



    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'views/frontend/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
        // Existe uma view com esse nome, vamos carregá-la
        $this->template->load('pages', $page, $data,'default');
    } else {
        if ($this->paginas_model->paginaExisteNoDb($page) == true) {
            // Existe essa página no banco de dados, vamos carregá-la
            $data['menu_ativo'] = $this->menus_model->getPageMenuAtivo($page);
            $this->template->load_from_db('pages', $page, $data, 'default');
        } else {
            // Não exite nem view, nem no banco. Erro 404.
            $this->template->load('pages', 'not_found', $data, 'default');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

opa!

```
Message: Undefined variable: Buscar
```

Variavel não definida

```
$dados["Buscar"] = array('Buscar' => $lista);
```

você tem que passar o nome da variavel como ["nome da varialvel"] se não o codeigniter não encontra.
Boa sorte

Comment: Caro Gustado não creio que seja isso, porque se fosse teria funcionado só com `$dados = array('Buscar' => $lista);`, isso não é nome de var `$dados["Buscar"]`, é uma maneira **forçada** de fazer o php a gerar uma array que seria o mesmo que `$dados = array( "Buscar" => array('Buscar' => $lista) );
`, no caso vc criou uma array dentro de outra... O CI provavelmente usa o extract() para gerar as vars no views, logo o problema ou é o escopo dentro do view, provavelmente ele esta usando "sections" ou algum "include" de outra view. Por isso a sub-view dele não tem como obter o valor.

Comment: sim sim, notei agora que ele está fazendo algo estranho .php 
$this->load->view('blogview', $data);

Comment: Caro Gustavo, nao tem nenhum blogview no código dele. A sintaxe dele parece correta, é mais provavel que seja o escopo da variavel mesmo.